# Выбор случайных элементов комбобокса C# WF

Tags: c#

При нажатии на кнопку должен выбираться случайный элемент из комбобокса.
Вот код:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = ( 0 | 1 ); 
    }
```

При первом клике на баттон выбирается рандомное значение. При последующих - значения не меняются. В чем проблема?

Comment: А где тут случайность?

Answer (score 1):

Как уже выше сказал @demonplus, у Вас не происходит случайный выбор значения.

```cs
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int max = comboBox1.Items.Count;
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = rnd.Next(max); 
}
```

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Random Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Лучше создание rnd вынести в инициализацию отдельного поля формы/окна. Мелочь, конечно, на производительность не повлияет, но все же

Comment: max все-таки должен быть равен comboBox1.Items.Count, рандом идет "до" значения, а не "по"